# How optimize my code adn must be invoking function to solve this question

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void f(int *p,int n,int *min,int *max)
{
    int *a=p;
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        if(p[i]>=p[i+1])
        {
            int temp=0;
            temp=p[i];
            p[i]=p[i+1];
            p[i+1]=temp;
        }
    }
    *max=p[i];
    for(i=0;i<n-2;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]<=a[i+1])
        {
            int temp=0;
            temp=a[i];
            a[i]=a[i+1];
            a[i+1]=temp;
        }
    }
    *min=a[i];
}
int main()
{
    int i,n,max,min,a[100];
    while (scanf("%d",&n)!=EOF)
    {
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        f(a,n,&min,&max);
        printf("%d %d\n",min,max);
    }
    return 0;
}#include<stdio.h>
void f(int *p,int n,int *min,int *max)
{
    int *a=p;
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        if(p[i]>=p[i+1])
        {
            int temp=0;
            temp=p[i];
            p[i]=p[i+1];
            p[i+1]=temp;
        }
    }
    *max=p[i];
    for(i=0;i<n-2;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]<=a[i+1])
        {
            int temp=0;
            temp=a[i];
            a[i]=a[i+1];
            a[i+1]=temp;
        }
    }
    *min=a[i];
}
int main()
{
    int i,n,max,min,a[100];
    while (scanf("%d",&n)!=EOF)
    {
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        f(a,n,&min,&max);
        printf("%d %d\n",min,max);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That's the code's question
Input n (2<n<100) and n integers, write a function to calculate the maximum and minimum values of n integers.
my question:
There may be a problem with my code, please let me know if you find it.If there is no problem please optimize my coode making it better clean.
if you help a better solution than me please sending to me .I want to use fuction to solve it,so oher ways might not solve my quesion.
Thank very much.

Comment: Please do not post images: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: You swapped the array elements in the first loop.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

1.Learn to Structure the code first, its easy.
2.Here is the code......
N.B.:-> I have used D.S so I hope its not an issue.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}*head;
void createNode(int n)
{
    head=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    int i,data;
    struct node *newnode,*temp;
    printf("\nenter data for 1 node::");
    scanf("%d",&data);
    head->data=data;
    head->next=NULL;
    temp=head;
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
        newnode=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("\nenter data for %d node::",i);
        scanf("%d",&data);
        newnode->data=data;
        newnode->next=NULL;
        temp->next=newnode;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
void display(){
    struct node *p;
    p=head;
    while(p!=NULL){
        printf("\n%d",p->data);
        p=p->next;
    }
}
void min(){
    int small;
    struct node *temp;
    temp=head;
    small=temp->data;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        if(temp->data<small){
            small=temp->data;
        }
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    printf("\nSmall data is::%d",small);
    
}
void max(){
    int maxi;
    struct node *temp;
    temp=head;
    maxi=temp->data;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        if(temp->data>maxi){
            maxi=temp->data;
        }
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    printf("\nMaximum data is::%d",maxi);
    
}
int main(){
    int n;
    printf("enter n::");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    
    if(n>2&&n<100){
        createNode(n);
    }
    
    display();
    min();
    max();
}
```